# So Custom Weapon Bonuses automatically apply to currently made weapons?

Tags: fallout-3

In *Fallout 3* when you get the schematics of a custom weapon you already have you get a message indicating the effectiveness of the weapon have increase and in the Notes section of the Pipboy the schematics have a v# after them.

I am wondering however, if i already built a custom weapon like the Shishkebab and then i find and/or buy another Shishkebab schematics, does my currently built Shishkebab automatically have the bonus from my Shishkebab v2 schematics? or do i need to craft a new Shishkebab to get this bonus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does my currently built Shishkebab automatically have the bonus from my Shishkebab v2 schematics?

No, it doesn't, but there are no weapon attack/damage bonuses gained from getting multiple copies of the schematics. The 'effectiveness' in this case is actually regarding the 'Condition' (or 'Repair') that the weapon starts in when initially crafted.

This isn't necessarily a miscommunication, as a higher state of Repair/Condition *does* mean a higher damage output, and therefore a 'v2' or 'v3' schematic does increase the 'starting effectiveness' over a 'v1' weapon. But given that you can bring up your v1 weapon to a higher state of repair by combining weapons or visiting NPCs, your v1 weapon can be just as 'effective' as one built with a v2 or v3 schematic.

This is confirmed on the Wiki:

> Additional schematics do not increase the base damage of a weapon. As the base item is the same, the base statistics are as well. The change is in its starting condition (or number, for the bottlecap mine and Nuka-grenade), which does increase the effective damage of the weapon.
>   <sub>[Fallout 3 Crafting - Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_crafting)</sub>

For non-explosives, crafting a weapon will result in the following starting Condition/Repair:

- 1 schematic - 75% of your repair skill
- 2 schematics - 100% of your repair skill
- 3 schematics - 125% of your repair skill (to a maximum of 100% condition)

For explosives (eg Bottlecap Mine), obtaining additional schematics will give you another item from crafting a single set of components. For example, with v2 Bottlecap Mine schematics, each craft will give you two Mines.